# LinQ Order By on ViewBag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq

Im trying to order by  the registers i take from a LInQ statement before i save them on a List however im not able to do so the items keep getting disordered

**This is my LinQ**

```
 foreach (var item in db.Pos.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fecha).Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
        {
           dateday = item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
           var listItem = new SelectListItem { Value = dateday, Text = dateday };
           listItem.Selected = today.Day == item.Day;
           listdate.Add(listItem);

        }
        ViewBag.Fechas = listdate;
```

**But this is my Output on my View:**

```html
<select id="Fechas" name="Fechas"><option value="2016-03-06">2016-03-06</option>
<option value="2016-03-04">2016-03-04</option>
<option value="2016-03-07">2016-03-07</option>
<option value="2016-03-01">2016-03-01</option>
<option value="2016-03-02">2016-03-02</option>
<option value="2016-03-05">2016-03-05</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2016-03-08">2016-03-08</option>
<option value="2016-03-03">2016-03-03</option>
</select>
```

**And this is the output i need:**

```html
<select id="Fechas" name="Fechas">
<option selected="selected" value="2016-03-08">2016-03-08</option>
  <option value="2016-03-07">2016-03-07</option>
  <option value="2016-03-06">2016-03-06</option>
  <option value="2016-03-05">2016-03-05</option>
  <option value="2016-03-04">2016-03-04</option>
  <option value="2016-03-03">2016-03-03</option>
  <option value="2016-03-02">2016-03-02</option>
  <option value="2016-03-01">2016-03-01</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Distinct` explicitly states that the order of the results returned is not maintained.  You need to order the items *after* performing the `Distinct`.

Comment: The items coms from a db in sql how can i order before using distinc?

Comment: @ArturoMartinez You *can't* order before using `Distinct`.  That's the whole point of the answer, doing so is pointless, as `Distinct` is going to re-order the items.